# Use HTTPS urls for site logos returned by the API

Tags: feature-request, api, api-v2.2, https

Currently, the API returns resources like this:

```
"high_resolution_icon_url": "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png",
"favicon_url": "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico",
"icon_url": "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png"
```

When storing this in a table, then embedding the images in a page later, this gives mixed content warnings when using HTTPS. The CDN [seems to be perfectly happy](https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png) serving content over HTTPS, so can we return those links instead?

```
"high_resolution_icon_url": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png",
"favicon_url": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico",
"icon_url": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png"
```

Comment: Hmm, I thought they were returned protocol-relative at some point, maybe I'm misremembering.

Comment: @TimStone That'd be even better, but I stopped short of asking for that because I'm not sure how some mobile platforms would handle protocol-relative links.

Comment: I have not encountered _any_ mobile platform in the last few years that had any problems with protocol-relative URIs.